# How can I send Images to php web service?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to send my image to php web service. I convert image in bytcode and try to send it to web service but php web service want my image in file formate so please tell me how can I make my image in file formate and send it to php web service.

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform a file upload with multipart data, see [Upload files with HTTPWebrequest (multipart/form-data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data) for a example.